# Python Regular Expression problem with ""

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, dataframe

I have a string like:

```
['"country":"UK","email":"abc@vip.com","x_id":123,"level":0',
'"country":"UK","email":"bcd@vip.com","x_id":234,"level":1',
'"country":"UK","email":"efg@vip.com","x_id":456']
```

I want to get the x_id and level and turn it into DataFrame like:

```
x_id  level

123    0
234    1
456    NAN
```

I use the re in python but I can't get the result.
Here is my code:

```
data_raw=['"country":"UK","email":"abc@vip.com","x_id":123,"level":0','"country":"UK","email":"bcd@vip.com","x_id":234,"level":1',
'"country":"UK","email":"efg@vip.com","x_id":456]
data=pd.DataFrame(data_raw)
data['x_id']=data.apply(lambda x:re.search(r'(\"x_id\":)\d{1-10}',x))
```

Comment: Please look at your post after posting it, so you can fix any markup errors. Which there clearly are. The code you're showing _looks_ like it's actually entirely normal JSON strings, in which case you don't use `re`, you use the `loads` function from [the `json` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for each string and then get your data from the entirely normal Python dict that gives you.

Comment: At least try to solve your problem before you demand time from other people. [ask]

Comment: I have added my code into the quesetion

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas' `str.extract()` method, which takes regular expressions as arguments and is applied to every single element of a Series by default:

```
import pandas as pd

data_raw = ['"country":"UK","email":"abc@vip.com","x_id":123,"level":0',
            '"country":"UK","email":"bcd@vip.com","x_id":234,"level":1',
            '"country":"UK","email":"efg@vip.com","x_id":456']
data = pd.Series(data_raw)

x_id = data.str.extract('"x_id":(\d*)')
level = data.str.extract('"level":(\d*)')

results = pd.concat([x_id, level], axis=1)
results.columns = ['x_id', 'level']
display(results)
```

Output:

```
    x_id    level
0   123     0
1   234     1
2   456     NaN
```